# I know this question has already been asked but I’m super curious on how this specifically relates to my problem

Tags: python-3.x

How do I dynamically create variables thru user input 
I have a discord server and I need a bot that makes accounts and stores number variables alongside those accounts to track my XP system just curios how would I do that

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]


With that said you don't create variables dynamically, you create a single `list` and append data to it.

Comment: Tbh I haven’t tried anything outside the idea of a for loop containing an variable that I add to then connecting this to an account didn’t work came out all wonky